# FlvPlayer fullScreenButton Event

Tags: actionscript-3, fullscreen

```
var myVideo:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
myVideo.source = "images/video1.mp4";
myVideo.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
myVideo.width = this.width-100;
myVideo.height = this.height-100;
myVideo.x = this.width/2 - myVideo.width/2;
myVideo.y = this.height/2 - myVideo.height/2;
myVideo.scaleMode = VideoScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
myVideo.skin = "SkinOverAllNoCaption.swf";
myVideo.visible = false;
myVideo.autoPlay = false;
myVideo.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
this.addChild(myVideo);

myVideo.fullScreenButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullScreenVideo);
function fullScreenVideo(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    myVideo.fullScreenTakeOver = true;
}
```

The above code does not work. fullScreenButton in FLVPlayback does not work.

How do I use fullscreen button in FLVPlayer ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? Just to switch your video to fullscreen? You should not need to attach a listener to that button, it works out of the box in that case. Just check whether you have the appropriate settings set in your html params: it needs to have `allowFullScreen="true"`